# Incorrect result from dynamic programming algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve the Dynamic Problem question to find unique paths between origin and the last cell of a board. The problem is present on leetcode here https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths/.

The problem statement is -

A robot is located at the top-left corner of a m x n grid (marked 'Start' in the diagram below).

The robot can only move either down or right at any point in time. The robot is trying to reach the bottom-right corner of the grid (marked 'Finish' in the diagram below).

How many possible unique paths are there?

**I am stuck on a test case with m = 23 and n = 12. Can you please explain the inconsistency in my code?**

```
    public int uniquePaths(int m, int n) {
        return getPath(m,n,1,1);
    }

    HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    private int getPath(int m, int n, int x, int y){
        if(x == n && y == m) return 1;
        else if(x > n || y > m) return 0;

        String s = ""+x+y;
        if(map.get(s) != null) return map.get(s);

        int max =0;
        if(x < n)
            max = max + getPath(m,n,x+1,y);
        if(y < m)
            max = max + getPath(m,n,x,y+1);

        map.put(s,max);
        return max;
    }
}
```

On m = 23 and n = 12, I am getting 192184665 as output whereas 193536720 is the expected result.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve here `String s = ""+x+y;`, but perhaps you mean `String s = ""+(x+y);`. (And if that's the case, why use string keys at all?) Or perhaps you mean `x + "," + y`.

Comment: You  are storing map keys in a `String`. So if x = 1, y = 11, s = "111" and x = 11, y = 1 then also s = "111". So you cannot identify. and its a bad approach. You can solve this in Sigma (m *n)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This was probably what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into my comment. You can solve this in Sigma (m * n) with bottom-up dp.

Create an `int` matrix of size [m * n].

```
int[] a = new int[n][m];

for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
  a[i][m-1] = 1;
}

for (int j = 0; i < m-1; ++j) {
  a[n-1][j] = 1;
}


for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; --i) {
  for (int j = m-2; j >= 0; --j) {
    a[i][j] = a[i+1][j] + a[i][j+1];
  }
}

System.out.print(a[0][0]);
```

Comment: Hey Shantanu, Thanks for the solution. The approach which you have mentioned is the bottom-up approach of DP. Memoization also works fine right ?

Comment: Yes memoization will also work. But recursion puts an extra overhead on the CPU. If you can solve using basic teachniques use them.